# Calling a procedure and passing 2 parameters Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, parameters

I have been trying to pass the following 2 parameters to a procedure during the form load it works with one but not with two can anyone advise?

```
<body onload="UpdateButton(<%=esr_link%>,<%=job%>)">

 function UpdateButton(Link,Title)
{
if (Link == 1)
{
        alert('Updatebutton=1')
        document.getElementById("staff").innerHTML = "Trust Staff "  + Title

}   
else
{
         document.getElementById("staff").innerHTML = "Non Trust Staff " + Title
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output of this:

```
<body onload="UpdateButton(<%=esr_link%>,<%=job%>)">
```

probably looks a little like this :

```
<body onload="UpdateButton(1,salesman)">
```

you're missing the quotes around "job".
try the following :

```
<body onload="UpdateButton(<%=esr_link%>,'<%=job%>')">
```